# Flutter Recording on Windows not able to play

Tags: flutter, video, video-streaming, vlc, steam

I am using Flutter dart_vlc  player for streaming RTSP video; it is working good but now i want to record the video but not able to play in any player. I am able to create the recorded video file in mp4 formate but not able to play it. Can you help me on this ?
If you want any missing code do let me know

```
void startRecording() async {
  try {
    final fileName = "recording_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.mp4";
    final directory = Directory("C:\\Users\\vvsa\\Pictures\\Screenshots");
    final file = File('${directory.path}\\$fileName');
    record = Record.create(id: 0, media: Media.network('Url of the video'), savingFile: file);
    record.start();
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error starting recording: $e');
  }
}
```